# Expectation of $\log^2(X)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose one has a continuous random variable $X \in (0, 1)$ and one wants to compute $E[\log(X)\log(X)]$. Suppose further that one also knows that $E[X] < \infty$ and $-\infty < E[\log(X)] < \infty$, where all expectations are taken with respect to a measure $\Pi$. Is it possible to claim that $E[\log(X)\log(X)] < \infty$?

I have tried a few things, namely trying to get an integrable upper bound on $\psi(x) = \log(x)\log(x)$, but could not find much in that direction. Also found this really [nice paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689741?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) that provides a bound on the expectation of an **increasing** convex function $\phi$ [see Theorem 2.1 therein], which unfortunately does not seem useful because $\psi$ is convex but *decreasing*.

### Edits

I just realised that for $0 < x \leq 1$, the usual bounds on $\log(x)$ can be manipulated to get
$$ (x-1)\log(x) \leq \log(x)\log(x) \leq \log(x) - \log(x)/x $$

So if one could show that $-\infty < E[\log(X)/X] < \infty$, I guess we'd be done.

In fact the claim is **FALSE** in general, as demonstrated quite neatly by @pre-kidney in their answer.

Using the bound above and the substitution $Y = -\log(X)$ one has

$$ Y^2 \leq Ye^Y - Y, $$

but it is possible to have $E[Ye^Y] = \infty$.

Comment: I do. That is the "definition" of the expectation of $h$, also known as the law of the unconscious statistician (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Since $X\in(0,1),$ you always have $E(X)<\infty.$ What you really need is that $-\infty<E[\log(X)],$ don't you?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess you are right. Check my edits and see if we're making progress. Thanks for engaging.

Comment: This can be rewritten as asking if $Y$ is a negative real random variable and $-\infty < E(Y) $ and $E(e^Y)<+\infty$ then $E(Y^2)<+\infty.$ That might be easier.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I think we can use your astute observation, which I had forgotten about, that the expectation of a bounded random variable always exists along with the bounds I gave to finish the problem. The key step would be using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Do you want to give it a go so you earn the points for an answer?

Comment: Actually, H\"older's inequality, sorry.

Comment: @Masacroso, but $g(x) = x^2$ is convex, no?

Comment: @Masacroso so if we define $ Y = \log(X)$ as suggested by Thomas, we have that $E[Y^2] \geq {E[Y]}^2$. Am I not seeing something obvious?

Comment: @LuizMaxCarvalho oh, sorry, my bad... It is not enough to ensure the finiteness of $E[(\log(X))^2]$

Comment: @LuizMaxCarvalho in fact, the result you are trying to show is false, basically for the same reason that we can find random variables with $\mathbb E[Y^2]=\infty$ yet $\mathbb EY$ is finite. See my answer for an explicit counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to correctly make such a claim. Indeed, here is an explicit counterexample.

Let $X$ be the random variable in $(0,1)$ satisfying

$$
\mathbb P(X<t)=\frac{1}{(1-\log t)^2},\qquad 0< t\leq 1.\tag{1}
$$
I claim that $\mathbb EX<\infty$ and $-\infty<\mathbb E[\log X]<\infty$, and yet $\mathbb E[(\log X)^2]=\infty$. To show this, I will use the auxiliary random variable $Y=-\log X$. Substituting $t=e^{-s}$ in $(1)$ yields
$$
\mathbb P(Y>s)=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2},\qquad 0\leq s<\infty.
$$
Using the [tail sum formula for expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value),
$$
\mathbb EY=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb P(Y>s)\ ds=1,
$$
whereas
$$
\mathbb E[Y^2]=\int_0^{\infty}2s\cdot \mathbb P(Y>s)\ ds=\infty.
$$

Finally, since $X\leq 1$ holds with probability $1$, it follows that $\mathbb EX\leq 1$ and in particular $\mathbb EX<\infty$. Thus we have found an $X$ satisfying all of the hypotheses, but with $\mathbb E[(\log X)^2]=\mathbb E[Y^2]=\infty$, contradicting the claim.

Comment: Neat, thanks. I was not aware of the tail sum formula for the expectation. + 1.